# Polymer Clone Objects

Tags: object, clone, polymer

How can we clone an object in Polymer?

Example

```
this.colorsAsc.push({color: 'red'});
this.colorsDesc = this.colorsAsc.reverse();

this.colorsDesc[0].color = 'blue'; // Both will be blue doing this
```

I can do it in these many functionalities [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) but I wonder if there is a way in Polymer to do that?

Angular does it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: You can use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs#clone) for that.

Comment: Polymer isn't a full framework, it's a web-components library. As it, it doesn't have a native deep copy function (as it doesn't have many native functions). As @MohammadWalid said, `lodash` is a good solution, for example.

Comment: I did it differently at the end, so I don't need this anymore. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Shadowbob could you please share your solution as many people will probably need an help on that behind you like me. thanks

Comment: @발렌탕 you can see what I did on https://github.com/hwebb/hwebb-load-bar. But this is for Polymer 0.5, not Polymer 1.0, and I didn't need that yet so didn't check if there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following hack:

```
this.colorsDesc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.colorsAsc.reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had [the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30005682/1878199), where I have finally also found and posted an answer.

Short version:

```
newElement = element.cloneNode(true);
for(var i in element.properties) {
        newElement[i] = element[i]
      }
```

Comment: this does not work if you are trying to clone light DOM elements inside the top-level ones.

Answer (score 0):

To clone a utility via Polymer

Full implementation:

```
  (function(callBackFn) {
      Polymer({

          //Component Name
          is: 'my-cloner',

          properties: {
              //Declare a published property 
              cloneableObject: { //Placeholder for Object to be cloned 
                  reflectToAttribute: true,
                  type: Object,
                  notify: true
              }
          },

          attached: function() {
              //Hide if this component got attached
              this.hidden = true;
          },

          getClone: function(incomingcloneableObject) { //Will be called to get the Clone

              this.cloneableObject = this.cloneableObject || incomingcloneableObject;

              switch (typeof this.cloneableObject) {
                  case "undefined":
                      return null;
                      break;
                  case "object":
                      var localClone = this.cloneNode();
                      return (localClone.cloneableObject);
                      break;
                  case "boolean":
                      return new Boolean(this.cloneableObject).valueOf();
                      //Other possible way 
                      //return(this.cloneableObject ? true : false);
                      break;
                  case "number": //NaN is taken care of 
                      return new Number(this.cloneableObject).valueOf();
                      //Other possible way
                      //return(this.cloneableObject * 1);
                      break;
                  case "string":
                      return new String(this.cloneableObject).valueOf();
                      //Other possible way
                      //return(this.cloneableObject + '');
                      break;
                  default:
                      return null;
              }
          }
      });

      //adding Util into window
      callBackFn();

  })(function() {
      window.cloneUtil = document.createElement('my-cloner');
  });
  //To use this util
  //window.cloneUtil.getClone();
```